# Javascript - text to speech with pitch and duration control

Tags: javascript, audio, text-to-speech, speech

I've been looking at making my javascript program sing.

I first looked at the web speech api, but the pitch control seems very limited, so I thought maybe there is a way to send the result to a web audio node, and apply effects from there but it doesn't seems possible.

I found the mespeak.js library: http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/

It allow to return a audio buffer that I'll treat as a source of my audio nodes, allowing for more control.

My input is a notes sequence, with a frequency and duration. Something like :

```
var seq = [[440hz,1000ms],[880hz,500ms],...];
```

I managed to get from this sequence and a series of words to my program saying those words in rhythm with different frequencies

But I'm having a few problems.

- The web audio detune is linked to the playbackRate, so pitching will change word duration.
- I only seem to be able to play with the detune or playbackRate values, which does not allow me to input a frequency (ex 440) and have the result in that frequency. The only thing I can do is approximate the base frequency of my speech, compute the difference to the expected note and pitch accordingly, but the result is not very good.
- I am clueless about how to deal with duration. Is the playbackRate the only way of artificially changing the duration of a word? How can I force my word to spread to a specific duration?

If any of you had any experience with that sort of stuff I'd appreciate any input.

Thanks a lot

EDIT: add some code

```
function sing(text,note,duration){
  var buffer = meSpeak.speak(text,{rawdata:'default'});
  playSound(buffer,freqToCents(note),duration)
}

function freqToCents(freq){
  var root = 440 //no idea what is the base frequency of the speech generator
  return 3986*Math.log10(freq/440)
}

function playSound(streamBuffer, cents, duration, callback) { 
  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  source.connect(compressor);

  context.decodeAudioData(streamBuffer, function(audioData) { 
    var duration = audioData.duration; 
    var delay = (duration)? Math.ceil(duration * 1000) : 1000;
    setTimeout(callback, delay);
    source.buffer = audioData;
    source.detune.value = cents; 

    source.start(0);
  }, function(error) { }); 
}
```

My sequencer is working, and at each step, calls the sings function if necessary, for example like this:

```
sing('test', 440, 1000)
```

As I was saying, I'd like the duration parameter to impact the result

Comment: it is easier, if you add the code, even if it is not right working.

Comment: Thanks, I just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espeak [supports SSML mode](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/ssml.html), you need to use it to modify parameters instead of trying to postprocess results.

You need to play with espeak first and then try to reproduce same results in javascript port. It is not supported yet, but in this part in mespeak.js

```
  '-w', 'wav.wav',
      '-a', (typeof args.amplitude !== 'undefined')? String(args.amplitude) : (typeof args.a !== 'undefined')? String(args.a) : '1
      '-g', (typeof args.wordgap !== 'undefined')? String(args.wordgap) : (typeof args.g !== 'undefined')? String(args.g) : '0',
      '-p', (typeof args.pitch !== 'undefined')? String(args.pitch) : (typeof args.p !== 'undefined')? String(args.p) : '50',
      '-s', (typeof args.speed !== 'undefined')? String(args.speed) : (typeof args.s !== 'undefined')? String(args.s) : '175',
```

You need to add `-m` option to enable SSML.

Comment: Thanks. I'm playing with it right now. The pitch seems to be quite limited in range but that will have to do unless I use a vocoder I guess.

Comment: espeak is vocoder internally, so it should allow arbitrary pitch, you may only adjust the internals a bit